# Retrieve login information based on user_meta

Tags: wordpress, email, password-retrieval

I have a client who wants her WordPress users to be able to retrieve their username/password even in the unlikely event, that they have forgotten both their username, password AND email address. Instead, they want the users to be able to retrieve their login info based on user meta data.

Users are created through a CSV-import, and their private email addresses are stored under a 'user_private_email' `user_meta` key. Users are invited to join the site via this mail address, but when they log in the first time, they are prompted to enter their work email. So this overwrites `$user_email` in `wp_user`.

My question is: How do I get WP to also check the `get_user_meta($user_id, 'user_private_email', true);` variable, and use this to resend the login info?